# Is it legal to explicitly call base class destructor/constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, destructor

Is it legal to destruct and construct a base class object in place to reset the portion of the state known to the base class?

```
class C : public BaseClass {...};

C c;
c.BaseClass::~BaseClass();
new (static_cast<BaseClass*>(&c)) BaseClass;
```

Clearly there are other ways to achieve this effect if we have access to the source code of the classes. However, I want to know from a language perspective if there is a specific reason why this is invalid.

Comment: No. To start with, there is no guarantee that `&c` is the same as the address of its base-class subobject.

Comment: Fair point. I added a cast.

Comment: a `reconstruct` method in the base class wont do? This sounds like a X-Y problem.

Comment: It is nice question for academic discussion, but absolutely terrible idea from the perspective of production code. Write a method `ResetBase()`, use it in base destructor (to avoid doubling code), call if needed from derived class and don't mess with destructors in a way they weren't created for.

Comment: @Spook Would this code be possible if the OP did not have the classe's implementation,  or cannot or must not change it? I.e. could the user of a library do a placement new for one of its types? Provided the relevant ctor and dtor are public, of course.

Comment: If `BaseClass` is assignable, you could achieve the same effect with `static_cast<BaseClass&>(c) = BaseClass();` (or in c++11, `static_cast<BaseClass&>(c) = {};`).

Comment: @PeterSchneider If OP didn't have the base class and base class didn't have a reset method, it would seem, that original creator of the class did not wanted the class to be reset. Using the class against the idea of its original creator is something you definitely don't want to do in production code either.

Comment: My friend - when faced with such idea - always responds without any hesitation, "bad design". And actually, in 98% cases, he's right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not legal. You're not allowed to replace the base subobject of an object.

C++11 3.8/7 specifies that you can only reuse an object's storage if

> the original object was a **most derived object** (1.8) of type T and the new object is a most derived object of type T (that is, they are **not base class subobjects**).

The object you replace was a base class subobject, not a most derived object, and so is forbidden.

If you were to replace the entire object (i.e. call `~C`, then construct a new `C`), then that would be legal, but dangerous. If the constructor threw, then the object would be destroyed a second time at the end of its lifetime. That would give undefined behaviour.

Comment: Can you explain what stops the object being of type C? I am not trying to replace or change the object, just reinitialise the base class region of it.

Comment: @JamesT.Huggett: `new (...) BaseClass` creates an object of type `BaseClass`, not `C`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour However, only the base class destructor was called. I understand the OP is trying to "re-initialise" the base class subobject without destroying an re-initialising the entire most derived object.

Comment: Calling the BaseClass constructor only operates on a part of the object which is indistinguishable from a regular BaseClass object.

Comment: @Angew: Indeed, I understand that that's what the OP wants. But that's not what the code does; it partly destroys the `C` object, then replaces it with a `BaseClass` object, which is forbidden by the line of the standard I quoted. (I suspect the partial destruction may also be forbidden, but I haven't found a relevant quote yet).

Comment: @JamesT.Huggett: Neverless, it's forbidden by that rule. You can only replace a most derived object, not a base class subobject.

Comment: @JamesT.Huggett as mentioned in my (deleted) answer, `C` may have pointers to resources allocated by `BaseClass`, that's the reason for UB.

Comment: I think you've got it. Although I disagree that I'm replacing an object with a one of a different type. The key point is that you are not allowed to replace subobjects.

Comment: @JamesT.Huggett: Indeed, it's arguable whether the type can be said to "change", so I've removed that from the answer and just left the unarguable statement that replacing subobjects isn't allowed.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor will work (only) if it is virtual, otherwise you'll have a partially-destroyed object (which seems to be what you actually want given your comments, but is not legal).  The placement new should work but I'm pretty sure is not really allowed by the standard (though I think there is a decent chance it will appear to work).  And I'm not sure why you would want this, since the object used to be a derived `C` but after construction it would never be a `C` again, only a `BaseClass`.

Comment: The idea is to reset the state of the base object without touching fields added in the derived class. I'm not sure what you mean by "be a C".

Comment: Why are virtual destructors relevant? I am explicitly calling the destructor I want.

Comment: "be a C" refers to your `class C`.  What  your are doing here is totally wrong and will not work.  If the `BaseClass` dtor is virtual, the `C` destructor will be called, and the object will be totally destroyed, though the memory will not be deallocated because you didn't call `delete`.  If it is not virtual, maybe you will destroy the bits of `BaseClass` only, but I doubt it's guaranteed to work.  Instead of all this, just make a simple `reset()` method on your `BaseClass`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Calling the base class's destructor with `BaseClass::~BaseClass` will prevent virtual dispatch.

Comment: @Simple: ah you're right, I didn't catch the explicit `::` in there, my mistake.  Anyway the code is not guaranteed to work as desired.